# Как подгружать по 20 итемов ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть база данных гружу оттуда данные в `ListView`.

как сделать чтоб отображалась только 15 итемов и при скроллинге отображалось еще 15 итемов?

Comment: Просто интересно зачем подгружать порциями из локальной бд? Если данных много и боитесь OOM то используйте cursor, он не загружает сразу все данные, а подгружает и выгружает по мере необходимости.

Comment: а кто из локалки подгружает?

Comment: ну под "есть база данных" я подразумевал локульную бд. Если же это сервер, то вопросов нет.

Comment: Нет использую убд

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно отслеживать номер последнего видимого элемента в `ListView` и, в зависимости от него, *подгружать* следующие элементы.

Вот [здесь](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/) есть пример.

Для реализации подгрузки данных создаете листнер:

```
public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }
    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading &&(totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // подгрузка данных
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}
```

и устанавливаете этот листнер в своем `ListView`:

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
```

На самом деле тут как-то несколько замудрено все, можно сделать несколько по-проще, но в целом идея должна быть понятна.

**И главное:** я точно не знаю как прорисовываются элементы в `ListView`, но в `RecyclerView` при *быстрой прокрутке* элементы могут отрисовываться не по одному, а по два и более, следовательно, если Вы начинаете загружать данные, например, на предпоследнем элементе, то эта загрузка может и не начаться (так как предпоследний и последний элемент могут отрисоваться одновременно, и события, когда виден предпоследний элемент не будет). Поэтому, если стартуете загрузку на `K`-ом элементе, а всего элементов `N`, то стартуйте загрузку на всех элементах от `K` до `N` включительно (разумеется, проверяя, не была ли начата загрузка данных ранее).

Comment: понятно  спасибо )